# Run python script with node js not work when use While True keep listen

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have problem when I run python script in `node`. Python works normally for infinite loop to keep listing response, after I use node to run python script it does not work. I have used [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.org/package/python-shell) and [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process). Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Node.js is async.**

That means it will run the python process but won't wait for a response.

So if you need desperately to use the python script in a blocking way, you can use a synchronous method like [exec-sync](https://www.npmjs.org/package/exec-sync).

```
var execSync = require('exec-sync');

var response = execSync('python yourScript.py');
```